# Django/AJAX/JQuery - Simple POST troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I'm trying to implement the simplest AJAX POST I can think of because I'm new to AJAX and JQuery. The idea is this: I have a button, and when it is clicked I want to submit basic POST data to the same page (the page is: http://{{ my ip address }}/django/ajax/ ).

In my .html file I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pythonizer(){
        $("#msgid").append("it SHOULD post after this is appended");
        $.ajax({ 
        url: '/django/ajax/', 
        type: 'POST', 
        data: {'obj': "test string"}, 
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response) {
                   alert(response);
            }
        }); 
        }
</script>    

<div id="msgid">
</div>

<input type="button" id="myButton" value="click me" onclick="pythonizer()" />
```

And my relevant function in view.py is:

```
def ajax(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse("Hello AJAX")   

    return render_to_response('huh.html', {})
```

Simple, right? The problem however, is that when I click my button, the "it SHOULD post after this is appended" is successfully added to the div, but nothing else happens, HttpResponse("Hello AJAX") is not returned, the POST isn't working!

What I've written seems consistent with the documentation I've read, but I have a feeling I'm either missing something stupid, or trying to oversimplify the POST. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a JS error? Maybe the JS var "data" is undefined.

Comment: I've changed it to be more explicit. It's now data: {'obj': "test string"}. The POST still doesn't seem to be working successfully however.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know django or python, but the problem with your javascript is that it's not doing anything when the AJAX call completes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pythonizer(){
    $("#msgid").append("it SHOULD post after this is appended");
    $.ajax({ 
    url: '/django/ajax/', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: {'obj':data},   // <-- possible error?
    dataType: 'json', 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
    }); 
    }
</script>
```

This will alert whatever you write to the response (presumably "Hello AJAX").

Also, there's an error in your script: you haven't defined 'data' (as in `data: {'obj':data},`). this script won't execute as-is, unless you declared `data` elsewhere.

Comment: I recommend installing Firebug if you're using Firefox, or opening the Javascript Console if you're in Chrome, and checking for errors. You can also use the Network tab of each to see if your ajax request is actually going through or not, and what its status is.

Comment: if it just says "undefined" that's not an error, it's just because `pythonizer()` doesn't return anything- if you add `return true;` or something to the end it will say `true` instead. `response` is fine.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear- you would add "return true;" to the end of the `pythonizer` function. `undefined` is **definitely** not an error.

Did you look at the Network tab? You will be able to see definitively whether or not the POST is occurring by checking the network tab.

Comment: Okay, I got the pythonizer() function returning true now. Everytime I run the function, a Method: POST entry is added to the 'networks' tab in Chrome. The Status is: 200 OK. That sounds like the POST is working successfully... but then why is no alert window popping up?

Comment: maybe try getting rid of the dataType and contentType properties- since what you're returning doesn't match those, maybe jQuery is trying to be clever and marking it as a failure even though it came back successfully.

Answer (score 0):

May be error in here?

```
    success: function(response)
```

I can't tell you more without the debug info...
Is python receiving request at all? Maybe it's a problem that it rejects CSRF validation and you need to add and import it:

```
@csrf_exempt
def myview(request):
    print 'hello'
```

perhaps you could read more about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/releases/1.2.5/#csrf-exception-for-ajax-requests

Maybe its better not to go so deep at first IMHO?

So why don't you use another jQuery shortcut?

```
$.post('/django/ajax/', data, function(data){
                                 alert(data);
                              });
```

Maybe I'm mistaken with your personal code, but I think you'll simply figure it out with it's official help here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

There are two good things for this:

1. Firebug (Mozilla firefox and maybe some other browsers are good too)
2. Django Debug toolbar

They are good for debugging in both python and jQuery sides... Try to learn to use them... (if you don't already and I'm sorry to tell you such a obvious thing in that case :) )

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a JSON response.

The [jquery document](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) explains the different dataTypes that can be used. When `dataType:'json'` is used the ajax method is expecting the response context-type to be in JSON.

In the template html file try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pythonizer(){
    var data = "data";
    $("#msgid").append("it SHOULD post after this is appended");
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/django/ajax/', 
        type: 'POST', 
        data: {obj:data},
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    }); 
}
</script>
```

Try this in your views.py:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def ajax(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse({'message':'Hello Ajax'}, content_type = "application/json")
```